# Unable to login facebook with python requests

Tags: python, html, python-requests

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
payload = {'email': 'my email',
           'pass': 'my code'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    l = s.get('https://facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&amp;refid=8')
    print(l.text)
```

It doesnt log in, what is wrong with this script?  (eg. try it yourself, by putting in your own email/code.)

Comment: If you check the source of facebook's login page you will see that the form there contains more than just the `email` and `pass`. There are many hidden fields that you probably **must** supply in order to connect.

Comment: just as a note, your second link is for mobile as it starts with `m.facebook`

Comment: Facebook wants you to use their API. They prevent scripted logins with all kind of tricks, which change daily.

Comment: Klaus D. So what you are saying is, there is no way that I can login with requests, is that correct?

I know I can do it with selenium webdriver, but since requests is faster, I am currently learning it.

Comment: @dekel Which one of the hidden fields shall I use? And how do I find these?

Comment: All of them. And you need to view the source of the page to know them (or check the `network` tab in your developer tool bar when you submit the form).

Comment: I suppose its these, with the 'type'=hidden  
https://gyazo.com/ba24d6726811ffcd54f01fe65ee6a743

Comment: Dekel This isnt right, how am I supposed to add the extra hidden fields? https://gyazo.com/bbca3aa56bdd00c2ee67ca8c2cb8a5c6

Answer (score 0):

Like Klaus D. says, probably best to use the facebook api and see what tokens or items they require